# Apache mod_rewrite redirecting to base URL

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, mod-rewrite

I'm busy migrating a production codeigniter project to a new server. The current setup has been working fine for almost a year now but while moving to the new LAMP stack I'm running into a weird problem with rewriting the index.php back into the URL.

My initial thought was that this question would be better suited to SO however the code is exactly the same between the two instances and both are running Debian 7.5 and Apache 2.2.22 which makes me think it's a server config difference that I'm not aware of.

This is the mod_rewrite is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bookings/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Like I said this has been working fine in the current setup however on the new server links from the base page always are rewritten to the same page.

I turned rewrite logging on for both servers and the new server is doing an extra rewrite step that I cannot explain.

Current server:

```
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5c45350a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/school -> /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5c45350a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/school/event/1 -> school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5c45350a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'school/event/1'
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5c45350a0/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/school' pattern='!-f' => matched
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5c45350a0/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/school' pattern='!-d' => matched
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5c45350a0/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] rewrite 'school/event/1' -> 'index.php/school/event/1'
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5c45350a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/school/event/1 -> /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php/school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5c45350a0/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/ with /bookings/
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5c45350a0/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php/school/event/1 -> index.php/school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5c45350a0/initial] (4) add subst prefix: index.php/school/event/1 -> /bookings/index.php/school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5c45350a0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] internal redirect with /bookings/index.php/school/event/1 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5b3e057c8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php/school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5b3e057c8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php/school/event/1 -> index.php/school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5b3e057c8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/school/event/1'
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5b3e057c8/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:09:45:11 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7fd5c46fbfc8][rid#7fd5b3e057c8/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] pass through /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php
```

New server:

```
### First section is identical ###
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673240a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/school -> /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673240a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/school/event/1 -> school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673240a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'school/event/1'
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673240a0/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/school' pattern='!-f' => matched
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673240a0/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/school' pattern='!-d' => matched
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673240a0/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] rewrite 'school/event/1' -> 'index.php/school/event/1'
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673240a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/school/event/1 -> /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php/school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673240a0/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/ with /bookings/
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673240a0/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php/school/event/1 -> index.php/school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673240a0/initial] (4) add subst prefix: index.php/school/event/1 -> /bookings/index.php/school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673240a0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] internal redirect with /bookings/index.php/school/event/1 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f3367321b58/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php/school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f3367321b58/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php/school/event/1 -> index.php/school/event/1
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f3367321b58/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/school/event/1'
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f3367321b58/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f3367321b58/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] pass through /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php

### The extra redirect ###
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673220a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/ -> 
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673220a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673220a0/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/' pattern='!-f' => matched
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673220a0/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/' pattern='!-d' => not-matched
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f33673220a0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] pass through /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f336731c0a0/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php -> index.php
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f336731c0a0/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f336731c0a0/subreq] (4) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
105.237.x.x - - [16/May/2014:10:11:18 +0200] [www.domain.tld/sid#7f33674c04f0][rid#7f336731c0a0/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/] pass through /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/html/bookings/index.php
```

As can be seen above, the new server is doing the initial redirect correctly but then there's the extra section that always returns index.php. Any idea what could be causing this? I'm not even 100% sure that they problem is with mod_rewrite. I've run out of options and I don't know much about mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what caused this but I reimaged the server, reinstalled the services and the problem went away.